# Replace specific character from an Array of objects with another character in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I'm trying to replace character "/" with a blank space or a dash "-", but i can't seem to figure out how. I've tried some of the answers i've found here but it returns the same string. I have two set of arrays.

set A: elemnts = ["String1", "String2", "String3/"]
set B gets each character of a s string from A to evaluate, an replace in case "/" is found.

```
 for(var i=0; i< elements.length; i++){
          arrayV = elements[i].value;
             for (var j=0; j <= arrayV.length; j++) {

                if(arrayV.charAt(j) === '/'){
arrayV[j] = "-";
                 }
   
    
                }
    
                elements[i]= arrayV;
       }
```

This is how i solved it (i learned something today):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("inputCont");

for(var i=0; i< elements.length; i++){

      var rString = elements[i].value;
  
         rString = rString.replace('/','-');
        
         elements[i].value = rString;
   }
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Your array elements are strings; they don't have a `value`.

Comment: No, the console doesn't show errors. Each element from "elements" is a parameter to be send as part of a path. But i need to change that "/" to a blank space or a "-".

Comment: What do you get if you write `arrayV` to the console right after you set it to `elements[i].value;`?

Comment: the same String without change. I set A to B, so i can validate each character in B[i]. Then the result is returned to A. I get the same String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I use the function [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array and [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace the character.

```js
var elemnts = ["String1", "String2", "String3/"];

var result = elemnts.map(str => str.replace('/','-'));

console.log(result);
```

### Update

OK, I missed the part about selecting the input elements. You can "cast" `elements` as an array and then iterate over that using `map()`:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByName("inputCont");

var result = [...elements].map(elm => elm.value.replace('/', '-'));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="inputCont" value="String" />
  <input type="text" name="inputCont" value="String" />
  <input type="text" name="inputCont" value="String/" />
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this as solution but got error on .map not a function and start from there. I got it. elements has input values with the name = inputCont, that's why the ".value". I assigned that value to arrayV but nos as an Array, as a string so i can use .replace() on it. It worked. Thank you.

Comment: @AxelDiazIb I updated my answer. I missed the part with the `getElementsByName()`, so here it is.